# How to get all products programmatically in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, products

I am trying to export all enable, disable, visible for both, not visible, the only catalog, only search. as well if there are 2 stores and assign different products.

So I want all products if any case is there I want to list out all products?
Is anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. On the Admin menu, select System > Import/Export > Export.
2. In the Export Settings section, set Entity Type to Products
3. In the Entity Attributes section, you can include or exclude data to be exported according to the entity attribute values.

   - To include records with specific attribute values, set the required values of the attributes in the Filter column.
   - To omit an attribute from the export, select the Skip checkbox at the beginning of the row.
4. Scroll down and click the Continue button in the lower-right corner of the page and wait for the download.

Source: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/data-export.html

Comment: thanks. but I want product by code.

Answer (score 0):

here is an answer.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
echo $collection->getSize();
```